# time-series anomaly detection of stock markets

Tags: time-series, finance, anomaly-detection

I was diving more into anomaly detection algorithms and found many applications in various domains including seismic acitivty, IDS etc. However I could not find a single paper on Google Scholar nor on Semantic Scholar on the application to stock markets, but there are endless on the prediction of stock markets.

I just found these two sites, which briefly discuss it: [SliceMatrix](https://slicematrix.github.io/stock_market_anomalies.html) and [Intro to AD](https://www.datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection)

How come? Is it not as interesting as predicting the stock market price? Or is there an additional complication of stock markets, I am not aware of?

I would be very glad, if anyone could guide me to some resources on this topic.

Kind Regards